# "s" final en tiempo pretérito indefinido: -aste(s), -iste(s)

Tags: diferencias-regionales, verbos, tiempos-verbales, pretérito

## Español

La segunda persona singular del pretérito indefinido generalmente termina en "-aste" o "-iste". En muchos lugares, la gente agrega una "s" final a estas palabras (por ejemplo, *hablastes* en vez de "hablaste", o "dijistes" en vez de "dijiste"). Si la forma correcta es sin la "s", ¿por qué mucha gente agrega la "s"? ¿Esto se limita a regiones específicas, o es común en todo el mundo hispanohablante?

---

## English

The second person singular of the preterite tense generally ends in *-aste* or *-iste*. In many places, people add a final *s* to these words (for example, *hablastes* instead of *hablaste* or *dijistes* instead of *dijiste*). If the correct form is without the *s*, why do many people add the *s*? Is this limited to specific regions, or is it common throughout the Spanish-speaking world?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Es un vulgarismo que [debe ser evitado](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_022.htm):

> por analogía con el resto de los tiempos verbales (dices, decías,
> dirás...), a la segunda persona (tú) se le añade como vulgarismo una
> –s final, y así encontramos el vulgarismo:
>
> **Tú dijistes**

En España, es común encontrar esto en la mitad norte, como dice  [aquí](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103093223if_/http://espanolsinfronteras.com/LenguaCastellana01.htm):

> En el habla de las tierras donde nació el castellano encontramos una serie de rasgos dialectales, como el uso del leísmo (le como complemento directo: Este piso ya le vimos), laísmo y loísmo (la y lo como complemento indirecto: La dije que no viniera); pronunciación de la d final como z: Madriz; **aparición de una s en la segunda persona del singular del pretérito [indefinido]: vinistes**; uso del infinitivo para la segunda persona del plural del imperativo: ¡Traerme algo!.

También se dice en [América](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_022.htm):

> En la norma meridional del español y en las variedades lingüísticas
> americanas, también se encuentra este problema:
>
> **Vos dijistes**

---

It's a vulgarism that [should be avoided](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_022.htm) (translated from Spanish):

> by analogy with the rest of the verb tenses (dices, decías, dirás...), to the second person (tú) a final -s is added as a vulgarism, and thus we find the vulgarism:
>
> **Tú dijistes**

In Spain, it is commonly found in the north central area, as it says [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103093223if_/http://espanolsinfronteras.com/LenguaCastellana01.htm):

> En el habla de las tierras donde nació el castellano encontramos una serie de rasgos dialectales, como el uso del leísmo (le como complemento directo: Este piso ya le vimos), laísmo y loísmo (la y lo como complemento indirecto: La dije que no viniera); pronunciación de la d final como z: Madriz; **aparición de una s en la segunda persona del singular del pretérito [indefinido]: vinistes**; uso del infinitivo para la segunda persona del plural del imperativo: ¡Traerme algo!.

It is also said in [America](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_022.htm) (translated from Spanish):

> In the southern form of Spanish and the American varieties, there also is this problem:
>
> **Vos dijistes**

Comment: Vale la pena mencionar que decir que 'debe ser evitado' es algo puramente en contextos formales. No hay nada inherentemente malo en usar este tipo de construcción. La primer página que es usada como fuente en esta respuesta debería ser evitada, en mi opinión general. No se le debería llamar al español que se habla como 'museo de los horrores', es una pésima actitud.

Comment: Hay que tomar en cuenta que no hay una única conjugación para vos.  Las formas con -s, por derivsarse de las del vos reverencial (equivalente al vosotros moderno), no se pueden declarar definitivamente como incorrecto porque dependería totalmente del dialecto voseante.  En algunos, como el argentino, no se considera correcto, pero en otros, como el del Perú, sí lo es.

Comment: ¡Evitalo! Si hablas de esa manera en México, eres considero como una persona naca.

Answer (score 4):

As to *why* people use it being incorrect, I guess it has to do with the *second person plural* being similar, but ended in *s* (-asteis, -isteis), mixed with what they hear around them and a certain illiteracy or carelessness about language.

And about where it is used, I can´t really tell. I know in Spain there are regions where it is more prevalent (e.g. the Basque Country), but I don't know about America.

Comment: In Perú we don't conjugate "vosotros" (-asteis, -isteis) but "ustedes" (-aron,-eron) and people also use the incorrect form ended in s.

Comment: What @Ricardo said applies to Mexico too.  It always seemed more likely to me that these people are overcorrecting.  After all, all the other tú conjugations *do* end in -s.

Answer (score 4):

It is extremely common in El Salvador. In fact, many people in El Salvador almost never pronounce terminal s except at the end of the second person preterite. Examples are "do vece", "entonce", "ma o meno", but "oistes" and "hablastes".

Comment: Esto también es típico en España, sobre todo en Andalucía.

Comment: That's really confusing :P

Comment: What are you answering to? He's talking about ADDING an -s, not to omitting them.

Answer (score 3):

To give a full answer, we must define what type of conjugation we're doing.  You've said second person singular, but there are three (!) different pronouns that can refer to singular things in the second person: tú, usted, and the oft forgotten vos.

If the intended pronoun/person is *usted*, then we use the third-person singular conjugation and there's no question there.

If the intended pronoun/person is *tú*, then there is categorically no *-s*.  The only endings for *tú* in the preterite are *-aste* and *-iste*.

**However**, if the intended pronoun/person is *vos*, things get more complicated.  The verbal forms for *vos* never coallesced into a single panhispanic conjugation (actually, more technically, they split off from a single one, but that's a bit beside the point).  As a result, the standard conjugations for *vos* vary by region and register, and what is correct in one circumstance is wrong in another.  The following are forms that are standard in one or more regions according to the *Nueva Gramática Española* (ASALE/RAE):

- **hablar**: hablasteis, hablastes, hablaste, hablates, hablate
- **comer**: comisteis, comistes, comiste, comites, comite
- **vivir**: vivisteis, vivistes, visiste, vivites, vivite

The forms that end in *-steis* are exclusive to the *vos reverencial*.  The forms that end in *-ste* are generally just *tuteante* forms that have fallen into the *vos* paradigm, although in some cases they are in fact derived from the *-steis* form, both monophthongizing and losing the *-s*.

If you just hear someone say something like *¿Ya comistes hoy?*, they may be completely wrong, but if they are a *voseante* speaker, then depending on their particular *vos* paradigm, they may be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Es sin -s. Me imagino que te refieres al pretérito perfecto simple.
Por ejemplo el verbo **jugar** sería:

```
(yo) jugué
(tú) jugaste
(él) jugó
(nosotros) jugamos
(vosotros) jugasteis
(ellos) jugaron
```

Si quieres conjugar verbos te aconsejo la siguiente pagina:

http://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol.html

La página se puede poner en inglés, alemán, italiano, francés....

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que surge esta polémica lingüística me pesan como losas los tercetos del soneto X de Garcilaso, “Dulces Prendas”:

> ¡Oh dulces prendas, por mi mal halladas,
>   dulces y alegres cuando Dios quería,
>     juntas estáis en la memoria mía,
>   y con ella en mi muerte conjuradas.
>
> ¿Quién me dijera, cuando en las pasadas
>   horas en tanto bien por vos me vía,
>   que me habíais de ser en algún día
>   con tan grave dolor representadas?
>
> Pues en un hora junto me llevastes
>   todo el bien que por términos me distes,
>   llevadme junto el mal que me dejastes.
>
> Si no, sospecharé que me pusistes
>   en tantos bienes porque deseastes
>   verme morir entre memorias tristes.

(Dejemos, pues, tranquilos a los que en estos casos usan con naturalidad las eses finales.)

https://tirardelengua.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/soneto-x-oh-dulces-prendas-por-mi-mal-halladas/

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: En el soneto mencionado el poeta se dirige a las “dulces prendas”, que por supuesto son de forma plural. Fíjate como también escribe *“a vos”*.

Comment: Pues en un hora junto me llevasteis
todo el bien que por términos me disteis,
llevadme junto el mal que me dejasteis.

   Si no, sospecharé que me pusisteis
en tantos bienes porque deseasteis
verme morir entre memorias tristes.(o tristeis?)

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be localized for Mexico.

This is a cultural thing.  Campesinos in Mexico use it.  They learned to speak that way from the people around them when they are growing up.  If they come into a lot of contact with people from a more urban setting, they may become aware of the difference, but they generally hold onto it, as a way of holding onto their cultural identity.

If a young person from the countryside goes to university and learns to write with correct spelling and grammar, s/he will obviously learn not to write "hablastes."  But there is nothing wrong with continuing the tradition, and asserting one's cultural identity as a person who was born and raised in the countryside, by continuing to use "hablastes" in casual conversation.

Yes, there are snobs who will look down on campesinos for the way they talk, and for plenty of other things.  But we don't all have to be Susanitas.