# Verbos en pasado que tienen una "s" extra al final

Tags: verbos, pretérito

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“s” final en tiempo pretérito: -aste(s), -iste(s)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/s-final-en-tiempo-preterito-astes-istes)

He visto que en algunos países, especialmente centroamericanos, terminan los verbos en segunda persona y singular pasado con la letra 's'. Algunos ejemplos serian 'comistes', 'fuistes' o 'jugastes'. En mi país usariamos solamente 'comiste', 'fuiste' o 'jugaste'. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta? ¿Con o sin "-s"?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Como te comentan, parece que ya se ha tratado esta pregunta con anterioridad. Si no responde exactamente a lo que preguntas, puedes modificar tu pregunta para que lo refleje. De lo contrario, se cerrará como duplicada. ¡Esperamos verte con frecuencia por el sitio! :)

Comment: See relevant [Meta post](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/248/12).

Comment: Me saco de la duda, pero la verdad es que no salieron resultados de la forma en que lo he buscado, por eso le hice post. Gracias por la bienvenida y espero ser un poquito mas activo en esta pagina(y no, no tengo acento en este teclado, por eso no lo pongo :-)

Comment: Sin -s al final. Con el verbo **jugar** sería: tu jugaste, vosotros jugasteis. Y es pretérito perfecto simple. http://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol-verbo-jugar.html